# rewrite rule nginx in external file

Tags: nginx, redirect

i am trying to redirect some specific url with nginx, I have a file when I put the rule, then I have an include line on the host

myfile.txt (the path is /home/user/Documents/myfile.txt)

```
rewrite http://mydomain.io/manuales/Manuales/10-BLD1001RGB/files/assets/basic-html/flipbook.html https://mydomain.io/manuales/Manuales/10-BLD1001RGB/files/assets/basic-html/flipbook.html permanent;
```

on my host

```
include /home/user/Documents/myfile.txt;
```

and is not working, but the problem is that i have some others file and is working fine:
i have redirects.txt same path and this rule

```
rewrite ^/10-downlight https://mydomain.io/es/10-focos-circulares permanent;
```

work fine.
Any Idea??

Let me say something this example is in localhost cause i write the rule on the file and the sysadmin apply on the server, i dont have permission to edit the host on the server